# When a paper has multiple corresponding authors, how should one respond to interview requests by media?

Tags: etiquette, interview, correspondence, academic-freedom

I've got two stories, one old and one recent. I'll start with the old one.

The paper has three authors, all corresponding. The first author was a senior postdoc who came up with the idea and did all the work. The other two authors' contributions are listed as supervision and guidance. The first author was contacted for an interview, and he accepted without telling the other authors. He almost got fired (he was too useful to fire).

Now I've received a request (similar situation, I'm one corresponding author out of three; I conceived the project and did most of the work), and I accepted, while CC'ing the other relevant corresponding author. I was told that 'there are strict rules' for this sort of situation.

To be clear, I'm not worried about my response, or getting fired. The thing is, nobody talks about these rules, but I can imagine some sort of unwritten rules about seniority taking priority in the case of media interviews and appearances. Is there anything like a general consensus on this?

Comment: Did you accept the interview before you told other corresponding authors about the interview or after ?

Comment: I accepted while acknowledging one other corresponding other and CC'ing them. We have a good enough relationship that I'm not worried about my response. If it were someone else I might have spoken to them first before responding to the journalist. I did not contact the other corresponding author (who is only on the paper as a formality).

Comment: "I was told that 'there are strict rules' for this sort of situation." Well, obviously, you need to know these rules and, also obviously, formal rules should be documented. Ask to see this document, so you can follow these rules.

Comment: From a later conversation it became very clear that these 'rules' are not written down anywhere. Nevertheless they were important in the old story (that I was only witness to).  I guess I'm hoping to hear from others how one should handle this experience. I imagine there are no hard 'rules', but depending on the academic culture one might expect that more senior corresponding authors expect to be the one contacted first for an interview.

Comment: The point of having a corresponding author is to have one person handle stuff with the journal. Why are there 3 here? Does your institution have a PR office?

Comment: One author handled communications with the journal, but there are three authors on the paper listed as corresponding author. This is quite common, at least in my field - usually happens when there are more than one PI, or when a junior author independently initiated the project. We do have a PR office. Both our PR office and the journal created press releases. In both cases referred to here, a journalist contacted the first corresponding author, rather than contacting the journal or the PR office.

Comment: @jomimc The press release should name a contact person. Journalists will always prefer contacting a person over an institutional email address or phone number.